# Redirect Page based on US State, using Maxmind geoip2 JS

Tags: javascript, redirect, geoip, maxmind

I would love some help in re-directing a page, based on which US state a visitor has arrived from.

For quite a while, I was using the legacy script, as follows, which was so simple and easy to use - all I had to do was paste this into my html file after the  tag and it worked:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript">

var user_state = geoip_region();

if( user_state == "NY")
window.location = "http://example.com/new-york-page/";

else if( user_state == "TX")
window.location = "http://example.com/texas-page/";

</script>
```

So, if the user was from Texas, or New York, they got re-directed, but otherwise, they just went on to get the page that I had embedded this code on.

But then recently, that stopped working, apparently this free legacy script from maxmind is no longer working (gives a 404 error) and they have gone 'paid for' only.

So, I paid to use their newer, geoip2 script and replaced the first line with the geoip2 code, to give me this:

```
<script src="http://js.maxmind.com/js/apis/geoip2/v2.1/geoip2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="JavaScript">

var user_state = geoip_region();

if( user_state == "NY")
window.location = "http://example.com/new-york-page/";

else if( user_state == "TX")
window.location = "http://example.com/texas-page/";

</script>
```

But I found that it doesn't work.

I've been trying to understand the geoip tutorials on their site, but they are so complex, I am really struggling. I'm looking for something that is as simple and easy to use as the first example was - i.e. something I can just copy and paste into my page after the  tag.

Anyone have any thoughts, is it still possible to do an easy re-direct, based on which State a visitor arrives at a webpage from, using the geoip2 script, as opposed to the old legacy one?

Answer (score 1):

There is no function `geoip_region` in that module. But there is an object `geoip2`. I'm not sure about state (you need to look into their documentation), but to get city you need to make a call `geoip2.city()`.

Comment: Thanks troolee, that is useful to know I can call the City through the geoip2 object. Been searching the documentation to try and find a call for the region, but without success.Wondering if this is not possible and I have to upload the database myself...